# How to exclude LAN traffic with iptraf-ng?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I'd like to use `iptraf-ng` to see how much data my machine is sending/receiving from the Internet, but I want to exclude traffic on my LAN as I am only interested in data going off-site.

I have created a filter as follows, but when I activate it, `iptraf-ng` shows no traffic at all!

- Source IP address: `192.168.0.0`
- Source wildcard mask: `255.255.255.255`
- Destination IP address: `192.168.0.0`
- Destination wildcard mask: `255.255.255.255`
- Protocols: `All IP`, `TCP`, `UDP`, `ICMP` (actual values set or unset make no difference)
- Include/exclude: `E` (if I change it to `I` there is no difference)
- Match opposite: `N` (if I change it to `Y` there is no difference)

This is making me think either the filters are completely broken, or I am really misunderstanding how they work.

How should I create an `iptraf-ng` filter that excludes all traffic where both the source and destination IPs are in 192.168.0.0/24?

Comment: If you are not particular on using iptraf-ng, you can look at `iftop`. Amazing tool. If its an RHEL/Fedora machine, its available in the epel repository. Use the `iftop` command after a `yum install iftop` and you will just love it :).

Comment: @Sree: I'm running Arch and already have `iftop` installed, but I can't see how to filter out the LAN traffic either.  The whole display gets clogged up with all the high bandwidth LAN traffic and I can't then see what much smaller traffic is leaving the network.  How do you filter out LAN traffic with `iftop`?

Comment: @Malvineous supply filters on the command line. E.g. `iftop -f "not dst port 22 and not src port 22"` to exclude all SSH traffic. Search for the "pcap syntax" for specs of the filtering syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two things should be noted:

- "Match opposite" does not mean "reverse the sense of the filter". What it means is "Match both incoming and outgoing traffic for the hosts/ports in the filter".
- Once a filter is in place, any packet that doesn't match the filter is discarded. So if you use an exclusion filter, it's important to complete it with an "accept all" rule, otherwise nothing is matched!

With that in mind, the way to define a filter to exclude LAN is:

- Create a filter, give it a name. When you get to the screen for adding filter, add the following:

  - IP address: 192.168.0.0
  - Wildcard mask: 255.255.0.0
  - Skip the port range and the destination IP/wildcard/port
  - Put Y in "All IP"
  - Put E in "Include/Exclude"
  - Put Y in "Match opposite"
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to add this rule to the filter, then <kbd>a</kbd> to add another rule:

  - Skip all address fields
  - Put Y in "All IP"
  - Put I in "Include/Exclude"
  - Put N in "Match opposite"

  This one is the "allow all" rule. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to accept it.
- Back in the filter screen, press <kbd>x</kbd> to exit. Select "Apply filter..." from the menu and apply the new filter you have created.

You now have a filter that accept everything - except traffic coming or going from the LAN.

(In my case, I used it to filter port 22, as I was connecting to the machine I wanted to check via ssh, and the `iptraf` output itself was causing most of the traffic because it was going through ssh).

Comment: WTF, thanks a lot, this helped.  Two Clues at my side:  **`Put Y in "All IP"`** - I left it empty in the 2nd rule, hence it matches nothing.  And then I had to delete the include-rule (2nd rule) again, because I "insert"ed it, so it went to the top.  There seems to be no way to move rules to reorder such that **the 2nd rule is 2nd**.